# jQuery appending remove button to list keeps adding an extra button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list which i want users to be able to add another one by clicking a button.  When the list gets added a remove button should appear.

Whenever I keep adding a new item there is an extra close button being appended resulting in something like this

```
.
..
...
....
.....
......
```

here is my js

```
 $('a').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var a = $(this).closest('form').find('ol, li').last().html();
   console.log(a);
    var closeButton = "<a href='#' class='remove-upgrade-field'>Remove</a>" 
    $('<li>' + a + closeButton + '</li>' ).appendTo('ol');

 });

 $('.remove-upgrade-field').live('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest('li').remove();
 });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rickyahn0612/3EhRx/)

Comment: you're literally appending the close button every time.  You have to remove the close button from your append and do it only on the first time.  Then add all of your new lists above it

Comment: What's this `.find('ol, li')` supposed to do?

Comment: the .find('ol, li') finds my last li element and grabs the html for it

Comment: ntgCleaner - how would i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to this:

**js**

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var a = $(this).closest('form').find('ol, li').last().children().html()
    console.log(a);
    var closeButton;
    closeButton = "<a href='#' class='remove-upgrade-field'>Remove</a>" 
    $('<li>' + a + closeButton + '</li>' ).appendTo('ol');

});

$('.remove-upgrade-field').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3EhRx/4/)

Comment: When another item gets listed the name boba fett changes to remove or undefined

Answer (score 0):

It is becuase `var closebutton` is append each time you click it with

```
"<a href='#' class='remove-upgrade-field'>Remove</a>" 
    $('<li>' + a + closeButton + '</li>' ).appendTo('ol');
```

Try logging the o/p of closebutton in the console.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I understand thats whats happening.....I just cant figure out how to stop that from happening